# Unable to output result of query on web framework using Google App Engine Datastore on Python

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I am making an app on Google App Engine and I have managed to store data on it's Datastore. However, I am not able to output any of my queries from the Datastore. My code is as follows.

```
class twitternames(db.Model):
    retweetersids = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    retweetersnames = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    user_input = db.StringProperty(required= True)
    datetimeadded = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)

q = twitternames.all()
q.filter ("retweetersnames=", "eriklikestorawr")

for p in q.run():
    self.response.write(p.retweetersids)
```

I am trying to give `retweetersnames` and get `retweetersids`. The following is a snapshot of stored data on the datastore.[image: Snapshot of saved data]

Your help much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Is your post properly formatted? It appears that your query is indented in the scope of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it. I was using post request instead of get.